# Check bit is set or not given its position in java (A Hackerrank problem)

Tags: java

I initially did this program like this, where given number and 2^k (2nd input i.e position) are biwise and..ed and the result is equal to 2^k or not. However its failing one test case and I would like to know why? (position starts from 0 in this case and its right to left)

PS: I'm not looking for alternative ans as I found it myself and completed the problem, but just for an explanation as to why the below code fails in one test case.

The test case works when I keep `len & k != 0`

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;


public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        long len, i, k, j;
        len = sc.nextLong();
        j   = sc.nextLong();

        k = 1 << j;
        // System.out.println(k);

        // System.out.println((len & (1 << (j))));

        if( (len & k) == k ) {
              //  System.out.println((len & (1 << (j))));
              System.out.print("true");
        }else
              System.out.print("false");
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
    }

} 
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please clarify what your problem/question is.

Comment: @AlexRudenko As I said, I would like to know why the above code fails for some cases.
What else do you want me to explain?

Comment: @bha_1999 could you provide an input values for failed test?

Comment: your code doesn't compile, problems with the imports (missing `*` i think) and with `if( len & k == k )`: `error: bad operand types for binary operator '&': first type:  long second type: boolean`. also since it is an Hackerrank problem, can you please provide the link to the problem so we can read the original text and maybe try the tests?

Comment: @MarcoLucidi It does compile, both here and in my local environment (which is eclipse). And as I said, even on Hackerrank it passed 9/10 test cases, so definitely not a compilation problem. It just doesn't check one corner case.
Also, here's the link : https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/smart-interviews-basic/challenges/si-basic-check-bit

Comment: @bha_1999 `if( len & k == k ) {` **does not** compile. I believe it was @Morteza Jalambadani's edit that screwed things up. and the first 2 `import`s are broken too.

Comment: @MarcoLucidi You're right, edited the code now. It should compile now

Answer (score 0):

It should work. I wonder what is input values for failed test.

Check this one.

```
long len = sc.nextLong(); // should not be negative
int j = sc.nextInteger(); // should be within [0;61]
long k = 1L << j;

// if bit is set
len & k == k (e.g. len & k == 0) == true
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked.
I changed (1<<j) to (1L<<j) 
and that worked.